# Can't edit other Parse User objects , save In Background doesn't write in Parse Dashboard

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have been bonking my head everywhere on this problem , I would really need some help please !! I am pretty new to Android.

My problem is the following , I have completed the User Class with some columns , for example "Former Friends" which are a list of Strings .
I do a first query , then I find the Parseuser objects matching the query (which are not the logged in user) and then I try to fill those columns.

I also update the info for the logged in user

It properly works for the logged in user ,however I can't see the filled info for the other Parse object user

I tried modifying the write access for the first user (objects.get(0)) ,but it doesn't work

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();


 query.whereNotEqualTo("username", getCurrentUser().getUsername());

query.whereNotContainedIn("username",getCurrentUser().getList("Former_friends"));



 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
     @Override
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {



  if (e == null) {

  if (objects.size() > 0) {


// Here I just add the first object to a list and I update the current user data ,that works fine


List<String> aList = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("Former_friends");
                                                aList.add(objects.get(0).getString("username"));


                                                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("Former_friends", aList);


                                                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();


 ParseUser userfound =objects.get(0);

// The two following Lines doesn't work. I don't see "Any String" in the ParseDashboard "Name" columns..                                                

userfound.put("Name","Any String");
userfound.saveInBackground();
```

There are no bugs , but no update for the non-logged-in user

Big thx,

Serge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, in Parse Server, one user cannot change another user object directly from client side. If it were possible, a bad user could erase all other users data, for example.

So this operation requires you to write a cloud code function. You should have a cloud function similar to this one here:

```
Parse.cloud.define('formerFriends', async request => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.notEqualTo('username', request.user.getUsername());
  query.notContainedIn('username', request.user.get('Former_friends'));
  const objects = await query.find({ useMasterKey: true });
  if (object.length > 0) {
    const aList = request.user.get('Former_friends');                                                
    aList.add(objects[0].getUsername());
    request.user.set('Former_friends', aList);
    await request.user.save();
    const userfound = objects[0];
    userfound.set('Name', 'Any String');
    await userfound.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
  }
});
```

And then call the cloud function from Android like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("formerFriends", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
  void done(Object result, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // success
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello,
First big thanks for your answer. I think that I need to get the Parse Server configured, and deploy the main.js (which is somewhere) with this approach then.

It seems pretty heavy . Is the restriction inherent to User class or any class in Parse Server (otherwise I can create another class and try to modify the object)?

Comment: The restriction is set in the CLP (https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#session--security) and the User class is restricted by default. If you create a new class, it will be public by default and you will be able to run your code. But again, it is not a good practice, because a bad user could erase your data.

Comment: Thank you very much :) It is pretty clear now. I 'll continue reading the docs for the cloud function